# Getting error from server using nexmo npm package to send SMS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, vonage

I am using [`nexmo`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexmo) NPM package. I have implemented every thing according to the docs but I am getting this response from the server and SMS is not delivered.

```
{
  "code": "ENOTFOUND",
  "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
  "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
  "hostname": "rest.nexmo.com",
  "host": "rest.nexmo.com",
  "port": 443
}
```

I am implementing this as a [Firebase Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). This is the code

```
exports.SMS = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  console.log("This is the function");
  console.log(request.body);
  var json = JSON.parse(request.body);
  const phone = json.phone;

  console.log(phone);

  const nexmo = new Nexmo({
    apiKey: '******',
    apiSecret: '*********'
  });


  const from = '12017016978';
  const to = phone;
  const text = 'Thank You for using TPV Express. Please use the following link to download our voice-enabled Android app for Third Party Verification.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.patientdatascience.tpvexpress&hl=en';

  nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text, (error, res) => {
    if(error) {
      // throw error;
      console.log(error);
      response.json({success: false,data: error});
    } else if(res.messages[0].status != '0') {
      console.error(res);
      response.json({success: false,data: res});
      // throw 'Nexmo returned back a non-zero status';
    } else {
      console.log(res);
      response.json({success: true,data: res});

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Which guide are you following...you should point to this url `https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json`

Comment: i followed this https://developer.nexmo.com/messaging/sms/overview

Comment: what is response, you should write res.json

Comment: @BasilBattikhi this is the response {
"code": "ENOTFOUND",
"errno": "ENOTFOUND",
"syscall": "getaddrinfo",
"hostname": "rest.nexmo.com",
"host": "rest.nexmo.com",
"port": 443
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue is. It is not with nexmo npm package. The issue is i am on spark plan of firebase and this free plan does not allow us to call third party API's from the function.

I upgraded to Blaze plan and it fixed the issue.